# MATLAB PLC identification

Tags: matlab, plc

I need help with this assignment:

Communication channel (eg. Power Line) has non trivial characteristics which is the major problem in achieving high modem throughput. That is why, we would like to known Channels characteristic eg. as a channel impulse response and adjust modem to the characteristic.

Download and examine exemplary channel impulse response from file ( http://home.agh.edu.pl/~kwant/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/ir1.mat )  and:

```
* plot impulse response,
* plot frequency characteristic (scale in dB),
* plot group delay.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot like a homework question.

However, just some clarification about what you are being asked:

- First, [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) data from a `.mat` file
- Next, [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) 2d data

Plotting in dB probably requires you to manipulate the data first using a few simple calculations. Take a look in a textbook or online for clues.

That should be enough to go on.